# Find specific value array multidimensional php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new on PHP and I want to find the 0 and replace with the number that is missed, inside the inner array, on a multidimensional array. If the inner array has more than two 0's, it will be ignored and goes to the next.

```
$list = array("First"=>array(0,1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9), 
                "Second"=>array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
                "Third"=>array(0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,8,9), 
                "Fourth"=>array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0),
                "Fifth"=>array(0,1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9),
                "Sixth"=>array(0,0,0,3,4,5,6,0,0,0),
                "Seventh"=>array(0,1,2,3,0,0,6,7,8,9),
                "Eighth"=>array(0,1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9),
                "Ninth"=>array(0,1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9),
                "Tenth"=>array(0,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));

$countZero = 0;
    foreach($list as $lvl) {
    foreach($lvl as $ind => $val) {
       if($countZero = array_count_values($lvl[$val] === 0))
        $list[$ind][$val] = 45 - array_sum($ind);

        echo $count;
    }
}
```

I want all inner arrays, that have two 0's get only one, to have all numbers in sequence  i.e.

```
"First"=>array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Please, help me.

I tried this code below, trying to finde the 0's.

```
$counts = 0;
$newArr = array();
    foreach($list as $lvl) {

        if(is_array($lvl)) {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($lvl) - 1;  $i++) {
                  if(($lvl[$i] == 0) < 2){
                    $counts++;
                    $newArr[$i] = 45 - array_sum($lvl);
                 }

                }

            }
        } 
        print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: skip the replace, just recreate with `range();` but at a guess that would not be allowed for this homework

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: you could just use the keys

Comment: What do you think array_count_values($lvl[$val] === 0) does? Or array_sum($ind)? Or echo $count;?

Comment: Guys, it's not a homework. And, as I said, I'm new on PHP. All the arrays, contains ID's that must be count. I want to know how to identify the 0's on the inner arrays and count them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution using array_walk:

```
array_walk($list,
           function(&$numbers) {
               $zeroIndex = 0;
               foreach($numbers as $i => $number) {
                   if( $number === 0 ) {
                       if( $zeroIndex > 0 ) {
                           return;
                       }
                       $zeroIndex = $i;
                   }
               }
               $numbers[$zeroIndex] = $zeroIndex;
           });
```

- You don't need to count all the zeros. You just need to check if there are less than 3 zeros.
- I'm saving the index (position) of zero (`$zeroIndex = $i`).
- I'm assuming that the first number is always a zero (`$zeroIndex = 0`).
- The index of the second zero is greater than zero. If I find a zero when the index of the last found zero is greater than zero (`if( $zeroIndex > 0 )`), this means that there are more than two zeros.

Answer (score 0):

In fact,here is what I've done and worked.

```
    $list = array(array(1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9),
                   array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                   array(1,2,3,4,5,0,0,8,9),
                   array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0),
                   array(1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9),
                   array(0,0,3,4,5,6,0,0,0),
                   array(1,2,3,0,0,6,7,8,9),
                   array(1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9),
                   array(1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9));


        for($l = 0; $l < count($list); $l++) 
        {
            $total = 0;
            $countZ = 0;
            for($i=0; $i < 9; $i++)
            {
     if($list[$l][$i] == 0)
                {
                    $countZ++;
                    $indexZero = $i;
                }
                $total += $list[$l][$i];
                if($countZ > 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            $list[$l][$indexZero] = 45 - $total;
        }
     print_r($list);
```

TY all.